# .htaccess 301 Redirect Except Main Page for .html

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all URLs in www.oldexample.com/index.html to www.newexample.com/index.html except the homepage (www.oldexample.com/index.html).

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldexample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it didn't work. It is redirecting all pages.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```